# GTK+ equivalent to QDockWdiget

Tags: gtk

There is a widget equivalent to Qt QDockWidget in GTK+? I'm trying to find one on glade-3 but I couldn't find it.

If there isn't, what's the correct way to create a dockable widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also check out [libgdl](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gdl/stable/) - although it seems the documentation is sparse at best. This is what [Anjuta](http://projects.gnome.org/anjuta/) uses for their dockable components.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used either one,but based on the descriptions, I think [GtkHandleBox](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkHandleBox.html) is what you want.