# Dockable Windows in Glade

Tags: c, gtk, glade

I am on the godly task to create the best IDE.
However.. I was wondering if Glade 3.14.2 has a support for dockable windows.

If there is no support, how would one code using GTK+ would look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GTK+ equivalent to QDockWdiget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115242/gtk-equivalent-to-qdockwdiget)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628194 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280750

Comment: I think your answer in the last link is the most appropriate one, though this person explicitly wants to make an IDE so :/ in addition a note on GtkHandleBar (or whatever it was called)'s deprecation could be added too?...

Comment: What's wrong with [anjuta](http://anjuta.org/)?

Comment: @ntd `anjuta` is not active or popular compared to `qt creator`